# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type 'xx' to non-throwing function type 'xx'

Tags: swift

[image: how fix it?]

how fix it? How should I use **do-try-catch** correctly.
This is possible when I remove the error code from the catch segment, but I need the specific type of error, so how do I catch a specific error and use it?

```
static func request<T: HandyJSON>(
    target: StatusAPI,
    type: T.Type,
    success successCallback: (T) -> Void,
    error errorCallback: (_ statusCode: Int) -> Void,
    failure failureCallback: @escaping (MoyaError) -> Void
) {
    provider.request(target) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(response):
            do {
                try response.filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            failureCallback(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: it should be catch let error or just remove error

Comment: If you only catch a specific error from `filterSuccessfulStatusCodes` then the enclosing function will still be `throwing` because the compiler has no knowledge of the specific errors that `filterSuccessfulStatusCodes` will throw. To get around this, you could change the return type of `filterSuccessfulStatusCodes` to `Result<Void, MoyaError>`. Now, the compiler knows that this function can only return a `MoyaError`.